# try... except dealing with matplotlib versions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got machines with two different versions of matplotlib (or rather my students do).  The newer `plt.hist` takes an argument `density`, while the older takes a similar argument `normed`.  These arguments let me plot proportions rather than counts.  I thought I could run this with `try... except...` but I've run into a problem.

My code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N=1000
sizes = [np.random.binomial(100, 0.03) for counter in range(N)]

fig = plt.figure(1)
main = plt.axes()

try:  
    main.hist(sizes, bins = range(21), density = True) 
except AttributeError:
    main.hist(sizes, bins = range(21), normed = True) 

main.axis(ymax=0.4)
```

[image]

And here it is where I don't set `ymax`

[image]

This is running with matplotlib v2.0.0  (yes, old, I believe there's a dependency somewhere that is blocking our attempts to update).

What I believe is happening here is that the first attempt to plot is creating an error, but by that time it's already plotted the counts to the figure.  So what's actually happening is that I'm getting the counts plotted by the `try` bit, while the proportions are plotted by the `except` bit.

How can I best work around this while giving the students code that they don't have to modify?

Comment: I doubt anything is plotted before the AttributeError raises. In any case, to give you a solution, could you (a) provide a complete minimal runnable example, (b) state in which matplotlib version you get the problem?

Comment: Updated code.  v = 2.0.0.  I'm about to do a couple hrs of driving, so I apologize in advance if I don't respond to further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes you're right. The problem is that the function signature of `hist` allows for keyword arguments, and that those are only checked *after* the artists are already created. Therefore calling

`ax.hist(..., density=True)`

in a version, which does not have the `density` argument, will still pass it as keyword argument, similar to how you can pass any artist property, like colors, linestyles etc.

The only good solution here is to **check the version** in use directly, and depending on that use either one of the arguments:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N=1000
sizes = [np.random.binomial(100, 0.03) for counter in range(N)]

fig = plt.figure(1)
main = plt.axes()

if LooseVersion(matplotlib.__version__) >=  LooseVersion("2.1"):  
    hist_kw = dict(density=True)
else:
    hist_kw = dict(normed=True)

main.hist(sizes, bins = range(21), **hist_kw) 
main.axis(ymax=0.4)
plt.show()
```